# Fetching entities with different number of parameters

Tags: ios, core-data

I have several entities with more or less the same parameters but in different numbers.

For example:

```
EntityA : model, code, color, name
EntityB : model, code, color, name, country
EntityC : model, code, color, name, country, style, date
```

Because of this, I did not create classes for the entity, so it is convenient to add stuff to "entityA" by doing this:

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"model", @"code", @"color", @"name"];

NSManagedObject *newObjectOnEntity = [NSManagedObject newObjectOnEntity:@"entityA"
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
[newObjectOnEntity setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

I simply add more entries to keys and values and I can use the same code to add stuff to all entities.

But now comes the fetch part.

At this point I need to do a fetch like this on lets say entityA:

fetch entry for `(model = "abc") && (code = "zoltrix") && (color = "blue") && (name = "roger")`

if the entity is B, the fetch will also have `&& (country = "usa")` and if entity is C will also have style and date.

So what I am asking is if I can have a fetch where I pass an array of parameters, an array of values and it searches for the entry on that entity that matches all parameters and values  `(parameter1 == value1) && (parameter2 == value2) ...`

Comment: does an entity match if it's missing one of the keys, or only if the values don't match?

Comment: a fetch will always have the same number of parameters and keys, different entities will have different numbers. In my example, entityA, entityB and entityC has 4 keys/values, 5 keys/values and 7 keys/values. What I want is having one fetch code that can be used to fetch any entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what I am asking is if I can have a fetch where I pass an array of parameters, an array of values and it searches for the entry on that entity that matches all parameters and values

Sure you can. In the `NSPredicate` syntax you can specify the field name with `%K` and the value with `%@` (or other format specifiers).

(Check out "[Dynamic Property Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW3)" in the "[Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html)".)